# How do I switch from bash to zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zsh

I can start zsh with `zsh`.

How can I make it be the default for new terminal windows?

Will it be ok to copy my `.bashrc` to `.zshrc` to get things like my customized PS1 prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chsh` is the program for configuring your login shell. `chsh -l` will list the available login shells.

It's best to keep an existing shell session open when modifying your login configuration so as to prevent inadvertently locking yourself out!

I'm not familiar enough with zsh to tell you what elements of your .bashrc might be problematic to copy over.